# Error testing this function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, bdd

I want to write a unit test for this function with Jasmine:

```
getState: function () {
    var $selectState = this.$('#selectState:visible');
    if ($selectState) {
        return $selectState.val();
    }
    return null;
},
```

I wrote this test:

```
describe("function getType", function(){
    it("should return value", function() {
        var obj = {val: function(){return 'ok';}};
        var spy1 = jasmine.createSpy("spy1").and.callFake(
            function() {
                return obj;
            }
        );
        var dollar = $;
        $ = spy1;
        expect(view.getType()).toEqual('ok');
        $ = dollar;
    });
});
```

In my oppinion it should work, but it does not. This is the error message:

> Expected undefined to equal 'ok'.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: what is the value of view.getType()?

Comment: where is view being set?

Comment: `if ($selectState) {` is always true, but `return $selectState.val();` not. if $selectState.size() is 0, than $selectState.val() is undefined.

Comment: this must be the problem. but how do I fix it? where is size called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. `this.$` seems to be different from `$`, thus changing the test function like this solved the problem:

```
describe("function getState", function(){
    it("should return value", function() {
        var obj = {val: function(){return 'ok';}};
        var spy1 = jasmine.createSpy("spy1").and.returnValue(obj);
        var dollar = view.$;
        view.$ = spy1;
        expect(view.getState()).toEqual('ok');
        view.$ = dollar;
    });
});
```